Jenkins pipeline giving "unexpected EOF" error while doing docker push
I have a jenkins job where I am pushing the docker image in ECR. Please refer to the below code:
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label "${jenkins_node}"
        }
    
}
  tools { 
    maven 'maven 3.9.1'
}


stages {
    
    stage('GIT checkout') {
        steps {
            dir("$WORKSPACE") {
                checkout([$class                           : 'GitSCM',
                          branches                         : [[name: "${BRANCH}"]],
                          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                          extensions                       : [[$class             : 'SubmoduleOption',
                                                               disableSubmodules  : false,
                                                               parentCredentials  : true,
                                                               recursiveSubmodules: false,
                                                               reference          : '',
                                                               timeout            : 15,
                                                               trackingSubmodules : false]],
                          gitTool                          : 'Default',
                          submoduleCfg                     : [],
                          userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                                                               url          : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX']]])
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    stage ('Prepare image tag name') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "image tag..."
                IMAGE_TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'").trim()
                echo "DEBUG: TAG name is $IMAGE_TAG"
            }
        }
    }
 stage('Build docker image') {
           steps {
               withAWS(roleAccount:'XXXXXXXXXXXX', role:'dcp-jenkins-role') {
                sh  ''' 
                    #!/bin/bash
                    set -x
                    cd $WORKSPACE
                    mvn clean install -DskipTests
                    '''
                    script{
                    sh """
                        
                        sudo systemctl start docker
                        sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
                        aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username XXXX --password-stdin XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                        docker build -t XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:$IMAGE_TAG .
                        docker tag XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:$IMAGE_TAG XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:$IMAGE_TAG
                        docker push XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:$IMAGE_TAG
                        """
                    } 
               }

            }
       }

When I am running my jenkins job at first attempt, it is throwing below error:

When I am running the job again, it is successfully getting completed without any error. This is happening frequently and I am running my jenkins jobs on slave node.

EOF is just EOF, you are hitting a network timeout or a proxy error. Rather check your network. Or you have a jenkins job timeout.

Network is fine, there is no timeout added in jenkins job. I have updated the full job details in description. Please let me know what can be done to fix the issue.

Network is not fine - you are receiving an EOF. EOF means "the remote side has closed the connection" or similar. Because you get an EOF, I would assume network is not fine. I have updated there was no update to your question. fix the issue well, workaround would be docker push ... || docker push || docker push to try multiple times. Do you get more jenkins messages after EOF ? Or you might be getting EOF from docker daemon, like I/O is too slow.

Please check now, I have updated it. Also, please let me know what can be done to fix network issue as well

Can you ping me the entire docker push command that I can use to test first?

I am not sure about docker daemon, how can that be checked?

I added multiple push commands but it's still throwing EOF error.

How large is the layer that is failing to push? Which hop of the network is closing the connection? You need to trace the route and log the packets at each point.
